# R Shiny How to select input form data frame column (reactive)

Tags: r, shiny

I want to selectInput from reactive data frame column as code below but it is not showed anything:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput('region','Select region',choice=tableOutput('region'),selected=NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

data<- reactive(fread('murders.csv')) # this file contain 'region' column

output$region <- renderTable(data()$region)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But when I read data outside server function (not reactive) the selectinput is working normal:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput('region','Select region',choice=data$region,selected=NULL)
)

data<- fread('murders.csv') # this file contain 'region' column

server <- function(input, output, session){

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I think it is better to read file in reactive mode in server function, could you show me how to select input from data column in reactive mode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are planning on changing the murder csv file, there is no need for it to be reactive, and it can be a global value. If you are keen on it not being a global you can transform the ui in a function and load the data inside.

Version 1

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- function(request){
  data <- fread("murders.csv")
  fluidPage(
  selectInput('region','Select region',choice=data$region,selected=NULL)
)
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you really want, by some reason, to load it inside the server what you are looking for is [updateSelectInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.3.2/updateSelectInput.html). See version below

Version 2

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('region','Select region',choices=NULL, selected=NULL)
  )

server <- function(input, output, session){
  data <- fread("murders.csv")
  updateSelectInput(session, "region", choices=data$region)
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And as I said there is no need for it to be reactive, but if you really want it to be reactive, you have to access the reactive inside a reactiveEnvironment, in this case observeEvent seems the most adequate:

Version 3

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('region','Select region',choices=NULL, selected=NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  data <- reactive(fread("murders.csv"))
  observeEvent(data(),updateSelectInput(session, "region", choices=data()$region))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Good advise; I want to caution further against reading in the data in the `ui` part, because this is not where someone would expect the data read in part and therefore makes the code harder to understand

Comment: @ luismf: Thank you so much for your post, All 3 versions have run successfully. You save my project !!! [Expand my question]:  if I want read file from ui textInput such as: fread(input$file_path) I see only Version 3 run. Version 1 and 2 cannot read input$file_path from ui by fread. Could you share your oppinion ?